# Does dispatch_block_cancel release the dispatch block?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, grand-central-dispatch

without ARC, does dispatch_block_cancel release the dispatch block or it need be manually released?

```
dispatch_block_t work = dispatch_block_create(0, ^{
    //...
});

dispatch_block_cancel(work);    // Is work released here?

Block_release(work);            // Or it need to be released?
```

Assuming dispatch_block_cancel releases the block, what would be the difference between those two cases?

```
// Case 1

dispatch_block_t work = dispatch_block_create(0, ^{
    //...
});
dispatch_block_cancel(work);


// Case 2

dispatch_block_t work = dispatch_block_create(0, ^{
    //...
});
Block_release(work);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cancelation has no impact on memory management. You called `dispatch_block_create`, which includes the word "create." That means you are responsible for releasing the memory. Nothing will do it for you.